# Editing Title of Existing Custom Option

Tags: configurable-product, custom-options

I have configurable products with options.  I simply want to change the title of that option, but can't find a field where it is editable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the AdminInterface

`Stores -> Attributes -> Product` simply search for your attribute and click on it. this will open the edit view.